# How do I update permissions for multiple roles?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I want to update channel permissions for multiple roles in  an array:
As far I can tell is that I can only role one role using `c.updateOverwrite(Updaterole1, { VIEW_CHANNEL: true, SEND_MESSAGES: true, MANAGE_MESSAGES: true })`.

How do I update permissions for multiple roles?

```
var Updaterole = config.ModeratorRoles.shift()
var Updaterole1 = Updaterole.toString()
c.updateOverwrite(Updaterole1, { VIEW_CHANNEL: true, SEND_MESSAGES: true, MANAGE_MESSAGES: true })
```

Array:
`705044537030213675, 728956885968879667`

c = channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map through the array and then call the function. I am not sure what your array is called so its hard to give you a relevant code example but I can try

```
arrayNameHere.map((role) => {
    c.updateOverwrite(role, { VIEW_CHANNEL: true, SEND_MESSAGES: true, MANAGE_MESSAGES: true })
})
```